# Example where we should use __device__ and __host__

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

In `CUDA` combined `__device__` and `__host__` allows a function to be call from both the `device` and the `host`.

My question is: Is any example that using both will be really preferable that just defining `__device__`  or `__host__`?

Comment: I guess it is useful when a function is common part of both codes (CPU and GPU). For example, mapping `i`, `j`, and `k` to an `index` according to the same mapping method.

Comment: For another example, take a look in /usr/local/cuda/include/cuComplex.h   If you want to manipulate complex data types on both the host and device, you will need both types of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical example is using C++ classes in CUDA. In the CUDA C++ model, every member function of a class *must* be defined in both host and device code if that class is to be instantiated in both the device and host memory spaces.

The simplest possible case would be a trivial class:

```
class example
{
    public:
    float a, b;

    example(float _a, float _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {};
}
```

It is not possible to use this in class in CUDA, you must define the constructor in both device and host code, so:

```
class example
{
    public:
    float a, b;

    __device__ __host__
    example(float _a, float _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {};
}
```